# Forming a group from power set pairs

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

**Question**
I want to form a group out of disjoint pairs taken from the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ over a finite set $X$. An element of the group $G$ is a pair $u=(u_1,u_2) \in \mathcal{P} \times \mathcal{P}$ such that $u_1 \cap u_2 = \emptyset$. Are there any ways to form a group on these disjoint pairs of elements?

**Attempt**
I thought to use the symmetric difference $a \Delta b = (a \cup b) \backslash (a \cap b)$ as done for the regular [power set group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267708/does-the-symmetric-difference-operator-define-a-group-on-the-powerset-of-a-set), but for both pairs. Take $u,v \in G$ and the group operation gives $w$ defined as:
\begin{eqnarray}
w = u \circ v &=& (u_1 \Delta v_1,\;u_2 \Delta v_2 \backslash [(u_1 \Delta v_1) \cap (u_2 \Delta v_2)])\\
&=&(u_1 \Delta v_1,\;(u_2 \Delta v_2) \backslash (u_1 \Delta v_1)).
\end{eqnarray}
The term in the square brackets ensures that the new pair is disjoint: $w_1 \cap w_2 = \emptyset$. This is closed in $G$ since $G$ contains every pair of disjoint sets. To form a group: (a) this has an identity $(\emptyset, \emptyset)$, (b) each element is its own inverse (an involution), (c) I'm unclear about associativity. I tried showing that it's associative by expanding both $a \circ (b \circ c)$ and $(a \circ b) \circ c$, but I'm running into some trouble. So far, I have:
\begin{eqnarray}
a \circ (b \circ c) &=& a \circ (b_1 \Delta c_1,\; b_2 \Delta c_2 \backslash [(b_1 \Delta c_1) \cap ( b_2 \Delta c_2)])\\
&=& (a_1 \Delta b_1 \Delta c_1,\; a_2 \Delta (b_2 \Delta c_2 \backslash  [(b_1 \Delta c_1) \cap (b_2 \Delta c_2)])\\
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{eqnarray}
(a \circ b) \circ c &=& (a_1 \Delta b_1,\; a_2 \Delta b_2 \backslash [(a_1 \Delta b_1) \cap ( a_2 \Delta b_2)]) \circ c\\
&=& (a_1 \Delta b_1 \Delta c_1,\; (a_2 \Delta b_2 \backslash [(a_1 \Delta b_1) \cap ( a_2 \Delta b_2)])\Delta c_2)\\
\end{eqnarray}
The left parts of the pairs match, but the right parts need some work. So we want to check whether the right parts are equal, i.e. that:
$$
a_2 \Delta (b_2 \Delta c_2 \backslash  [(b_1 \Delta c_1) \cap (b_2 \Delta c_2)] = (a_2 \Delta b_2 \backslash [(a_1 \Delta b_1) \cap ( a_2 \Delta b_2)])\Delta c_2
$$
I'm getting stuck here just because this expands (in $\Delta$) to a lot of terms. Perhaps there's a smart to check this?

Comment: It is indeed tedious to check associativity for a binary operation plucked out of the air. Have you tried to check your proposed operation for some specific small set $X$, e.g., $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$?

Comment: Note that $B-(A\cap B)= B-A$, so you can simplify your formula for $\circ$.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do so? $P(X)$ also carries a ring structure with intersection as multiplication and $G$ is the set of pairs of zero divisors.

Comment: @Berci _why_: a problem I have gives these types of paired elements and I want to generate new elements to see what can be generated from my current elements. I  didn't think of making a ring, I wonder if it could be constructed for these types of disjoint pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your construction cannot give a group if your set has more than one element.

Consider $a=(\{1,2\},\varnothing)$, $b=(\varnothing,\{2\})$, and $c=(\varnothing,\varnothing)$. Then $b\neq c$, but
$$\begin{align*}
a\circ b&= (\{1,2\},\varnothing)\circ (\varnothing,\{2\})\\
&= (\{1,2\},\{2\}-\{1,2\}) = (\{1,2\},\varnothing).\\
a\circ c&= (\{1,2\},\varnothing)\circ (\varnothing,\varnothing) = (\{1,2\},\varnothing).
\end{align*}$$
So $b\neq c$, but $a\circ b= a\circ c$. This is impossible in a group.

---

In fact, one element suffices: set $X=\{\star\}$. Then
$(X,\varnothing)\circ(\varnothing,X)=(X,\varnothing)=(X,\varnothing)\circ(\varnothing,\varnothing)$, so again you cannot have a group.

(Of course, if $X$ is empty then you have the one-element group...)

---

You ask in comments whether you have a loop. The answer is no, unless $X$ is empty. Consider the elements $(X,\varnothing)$ and $(\varnothing,X)$. There is no element $A$ such that $(X,\varnothing)\circ A = (\varnothing, X)$. Indeed, such an element $A=(R,S)$ would necessarily have $X\Delta R=\varnothing$, hence $R=X$; but then the condition $R\cap S=\varnothing$ requires $S=\varnothing$, and $(X,\varnothing)\circ(X,\varnothing)=(\varnothing,\varnothing)\neq (\varnothing, X)$.

But in a loop, the equations $ax=b$ and $ya=b$ have solutions for all $a$ and $b$, so this is not a loop either.

Comment: Nice. So would my construction would be a loop instead of a group?

Comment: @mattapow: I don’t think so. With a one element set, you have three elements: $(\varnothing,\varnothing)$, $(X,\varnothing)$, and $(\varnothing,X)$. However, you can’t get from $(X,\varnothing)$ to $(\varnothing,X)$, so the equation $(X,\varnothing)\circ A = (\varnothing,X)$ does not have solutions. You don’t have a loop, either.

Answer (score 2):

Your operation need not be associative.

Let $X=\{0,1\}$, $a=\langle\{0\},\{1\}\rangle$, and $b=\langle\{1\},\{0\}\rangle$. Then $a\circ b=\langle X,\varnothing\rangle$, so

$$a\circ(a\circ b)=\langle\{0\},\{1\}\rangle\circ\langle X,\varnothing\rangle=\langle\{1\},\varnothing\rangle\,.$$

However, $(a\circ a)\circ b=b\ne\langle\{1\},\varnothing\rangle$.